# Save a model and related models in Rails using Angular 2

Tags: angular, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Requirements:

- Rails 4
- Angular 2
- MongoDB
- Mongoid

I have a one to many relationship, one ParentModel has many ChildModels. I want to save them altogether just like when done using a vanilla Rails application where in the form child attributes has the following input form:

`<input type="text" name="parent_model[child_models][mongodb_id][name]" />`

I'm NEWBIE to Rails
The way I understand this, is that the form name above causes the related models also to be saved. My problem now is that my forms are not like that. I am using Angular which means my forms are just the normal ones so it doesn't detect the attributes of the child model.

**Note: Please answer assuming that all the Rails Models part are correct. I think the problem here is the params in the Rails controller or maybe the way I am sending it from Angular.**

I tried sending it as `{child_models: []}` or `{child_models_attributes: []}` and still not saving it, I am getting the required error since this is required before saving the parent model.

How should I do it? Hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: as far as i know - angular suppose to act similar no matter what backend it consumes - be it c# or rails, i guess you should figure out what json your rails suppose to get through api call...

Comment: So you mean it's Rails which I should change?